# Best way to store and recieve 3d files on webserver

Tags: javascript, ajax, three.js

I am currently working on an online cake configurator. The problem I am having is that I am not really sure if what I am doing is state of the art.

The configurator uses THREE.js to display the 3d model of cakes. I have several 3d model of cakes, which can be uploaded by the user. Those models are stored on the webserver. Each cake consists of one .obj file and one .mtl file.

Now..what I am unsure about. What is the best way to retrieve those models from the webserver. I tried ajax, but as far as I can tell ajax is not able to return .obj or .mtr files.

So my question. Is ajax even the right solution for this or is there a completely different approach I should look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question. Is ajax even the right solution for this or is there a completely different approach I should look into?

Yes, this is the correct approach. Nowadays, you usually load files from the server via the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

But if you need the OBJ/MTL files for rendering, you can just load them via `OBJLoader` and `MTLLoader` and don't have to bother about the internals. You probably want to use the respective official `three.js` example as a code template: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl

Comment: I am using the Obj and MTLoader. I figured I need to retrieve the obj and mtl via AJAX to then get them loaded via the OBJLoader and MTLoader. But I guess since I use the loader I don't even need to bother with AJAX I just need to provide the URL where the files are stored, is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. Typical HTTP server should have to problem to serve OBJ/MTL assets.